# i get the error message on my server using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Im getting this error message using xampp i couldnt figure out if it was the code or i needed to configure something in xampp im using windows 7
it works usually but for some reason the _get crashes it i think

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

here is my php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET('day'))){

};
//echo $_get('day');

$text = 'Hello World.'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>



<form action="index.php" method="GET"> 
day:<input type="text" name="day"value=""><br />
date:<input type="text" name="date"value=""><br />
name:<input type="text" name="name"value=""><br />
email:<input type="text" name="email"value=""><br />
<input type="submit"value = "submit">
</form >
</body>
</html>
```

i know this question has been asked before but i couldn't find a helpful answer

Comment: that's your webserver saying you (or it) isn't allowed to access your script file.

Comment: @MarcB any solutions at least what direction to look in

Comment: Check the file permissions of the  php file, if Apache can't read it can't be served.

Comment: IIR xampp is running the httpd services under the [localsystem account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). File permissions for your script directory/files must grant read access for this account.

Comment: my php xampp works just when i added in the _get request it didn't work

Comment: @VolkerK so how do you change anything there and how can it be accessed

Comment: btw: `$_GET['day']`, when accessing an element within an array use square brackets, not parentheses.